# Cannot get index.html in webapp2 with python27

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I am trying to go from python2.5 to python 2.7 in google app engine.

I just cannot get index.html up and going. I get a blank webpage, and nothing more. index.html is in the same directory as the .yaml and .py files.

I cannot find out how to make it work, cause there is no such tutorials or examples or anything that tells you how to render index.html.

What I found are examples that write out 'Hello World!'.
I've found some 'almost there'-examples, but it's not quite there.

Here are app.yaml and main.py

```
application: myapp
version: main
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jif|jpg|jpeg|ico|js|css))
 static_files: \1
 upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpeg|jpg|ico|js|css))

- url: .*
 script: main.application
```

.

```
import os

import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template

class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def render_template(self, filename, **template_args):
     path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates', filename)
     self.response.write(template.render(path, template_args))

class IndexHandler(BaseHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.render_template('index.html', name=self.request.get('name'))

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', IndexHandler),
], debug=True)
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: It does not load index.html

Answer (score 2):

In the line:

```
     path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates', filename)
```

You're telling your code to look for your template to render in the directory "templates", not in the root directory of your app. Either use a "templates" directory, or remove it from the join.